# Curator mutex lock failed after reconnected

Tags: java, locking, mutex, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Scenario:

Using Curator to implements a distributed mutex.
if the client who already acquire the mutex is disconnect with zk server due to a network failure, then Curator will trying to reconnect. let's assume it's finally successful reconnected, but the last session is expired and the ephemeral lock node used for mutex is also disappeared, then this mutex not work again!

So how can I handle mutex fail after reconnect when using Curator? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the note about error handling with Curator (note: I'm the main author of Curator): http://curator.apache.org/errors.html as well as Tech Note 12: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CURATOR/TN12

The TL;DR is that if the connection fails (SUSPENDED) you should assume that your lock is lost and interrupt whatever thread holds the lock. If you're very careful, you can wait until the connection goes to LOST but my recommendation is to always assume that SUSPENDED means you no longer hold the lock.